# Angular - only input text in input type="text"

Tags: angularjs

So I have an input with the type `text`:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" id="last-name-reservation-form" placeholder="Last name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would I be able to filter on the input characters, such that it only takes text and not numbers? Sort of similar to how `type="number"` only allows numbers to be input.

Do I have to make something in the controller or can it be done directly in the .html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use ng-pattern

For restricting only alphabets,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" name="inputName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" >
```

For restricting only numbers,

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="myText" name="inputName" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/">
```

Comment: Had no idea you could do it like that. Short and easy. Thanks!

Comment: I plan to, but can only do 10mins after posting the question :)

Comment: i think its almost 12 minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

You could put

```
pattern="[A-Za-z]+"
```

in the input tag to make the pattern match.

Comment: Why `{28}` and not `*` / `+`?

Comment: I was just giving an example but thanks I changed it to +.